# Where are product uninstall keys located in the Registry under Windows 7 x64?

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, uninstall

I need to look up the install location of a product in the registry, based on the GUID product code. Under Win XP the keys of products installed were located at

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
```

For example, if I had the GUID {034759DA-E21A-4795-BFB3-C66D17FAD183} I could look up

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall{034759DA-E21A-4795-BFB3-C66D17FAD183}
```

and there would be a value containing the install location for the product.

However, the Registry doesn't appear to follow this same setup in Win 7 x64. Does anyone know how I can do what I did in XP, but in Windows 7? Thanks.

Comment: Looks exactly like that to me in Windows 7 Professional x64. Everything's right there in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`.

Comment: Related post - [Where does Windows store MSI files for uninstallation?](https://superuser.com/q/473569/374397)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just checked my Win7 x64 system and the registry shows an `InstallLocation` key for most of the entries.

Comment: But are the entries listed as GUIDs located under HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall?

Comment: Yes they are.  I just looked at your original post again and you don't have a "\" between \Uninstall and the GUID.  Could just be a typo here, but you'll definitely need that in the registry search.

Comment: That was just a typo in the post. Hmm, the product I'm working with doesn't seem to create the proper entry under Uninstall in Win7 x64. I just installed Java, and it had the keys where I expected them. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 23):

For 32-bit applications installed onto 64-bit Operating System, browse to the following

```
HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you are right about that.  Below is screenshot of my Visual C++ redistributables both x86 and x64, as you can see, none of these go to Wow6432Node

[image]

Comment: It depends on the bit-edness of the installer - not of the installed files (which can be mixed). Effectively the win x64 control panel uninstall tool looks up both locations.