# Where is studio64.exe located in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, path, android-studio, file-location

I removed the only shortcut to Android Studio from the Start Menu as Windows suggested me to, saying it's no longer usable. Now, I can't find how to launch Android Studio. I tried searching numerous paths like:

> C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin\studio.exe

> C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin

> C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Android Studio

The thing is, File Explorer says that it couldn't find the first and the second path, and the third folder is empty, probably because I removed the shortcut. How can I locate the `studio64.exe` on Windows 10?

Looks like [this is my case](https://superuser.com/questions/803112/how-to-find-location-of-applications-listed-in-add-remove-programs-of-the-contro#comment1048472_803121). Android Studio's location is empty (in `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Programs and Features`, [with `View > Group by > More... > Location` enabled](https://superuser.com/a/803121/1577795)):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Windows will suggest the removal of invalid entries from the
Start menu, if the executable in question is not found.

Evidently, you had Android Studio installed at some time, then you
uninstalled it. The removal was not complete, as it removed the
program but not the Start menu entry that pointed to it.

This removal could have been the result of some action on your part,
or perhaps the result of some over-active security software deciding
that this executable was a virus.

The simplest solution to your problem would be to reinstall
Android Studio.
This will restore the executable and also its Start menu entry.

If the problem happens again, examine your security software
for some reason for it happening, or add an exclusion for the
folder of Android Studio (if this is possible).

Comment: I thought of this possibility too, but I don't remember uninstalling Android Studio any time. Also, I don't think any anti-virus would have done that. Is there a way to find if it's uninstalled? Recently, I think some malicious anti-virus got on my PC.

Comment: [This post](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit) has advice about viruses, although Android Studio is usually not targeted by viruses. Check also if in "Programs and Features" you can still find Android Studio, and if it's not there you will really need to install it (it's much more than just one executable).

Comment: Oooh yes, how can I forget that?! Will check if it's there.

Comment: And yes, it's there. Is there any way I can get the path from there? I tried right-clicking; no luck.

Comment: You can search for the executable using Explorer. A better search tool is [voidtools Everything](https://www.voidtools.com/) (recommended). Remember that it might have been deleted. On my computer it's at `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin\studio64.exe`.

Comment: ...If the folder is still there with lots of files, except that this `.exe` is missing, you might need to restore it from the Recycle Bin or extract it from the installation,

Comment: No, I tried, but it couldn't find anything.

Comment: I still maintain that the simplest solution to your problem would be to reinstall Android Studio, even over the old installation. This will fix everything.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that Android Studio is still there on your Windows Installation, you have 3 or 4 or "MORE" ways :

**(1)** Check in recycle bin (Quick Check)

**(2)** Windows Desktop Search on whole C:\ (Slow Check)

**(3)** Check in Prefetch Directory (Quick Check)

CD %SystemRoot%\Prefetch
Check whether studio.exe Exists here.

If YES, then get WinPrefetchView tool from http://nirsoft.com/ and then get the Path to studio.exe.

**(4)** Reinstall Android Studio (not sure about this)

**(5)** Use registry editor (Slow Check)
Use "regedit.exe" and search for "Studio" and look into all the matches ; Check whether there is a PATH (or Binary or COMMAND or Similar) available. If yes, use that PATH.

Comment: I tried the first 2 ways, but both didn't help. I wouldn't want to install it again, and how do I check if `studio64.exe` exists in there?

Comment: How about the 3rd way ?

Comment: How do I go about searching/check if it exists in it? When I copy-paste it on File Explorer after `Ctrl+L`-ing, it doesn't do anything, probably because it needs Administrator permissions. I'm able to change the directory to 'Prefetch' with Administrator permissions on CMD but confused about how to check if it's in there.

Comment: When CMD can CD to there, you can type "EXPLORER ." [[ the DOT is required ]] to open Windows Explorer in that Directory. Now you can give Permission, and sort the listing and scroll to "S", and check if there is some Entry like "Studio.exe-XXXXX". If yes, good; If no, Studio.exe was not used recently and it has gone away Permanently.

Comment: No, I tried, but it looks like it's not been used recently.