# How can I perform an uninstall as an administrator with superuser privileges but without an administrator account?

Tags: windows-10, administrator, uninstall

My IT department has given me privileges to use Run As Administrator, so I can install software.  But when I try to uninstall using the Windows 10 Apps or the older control panel's Programs and Features, I get a login request that requires administrator privileges that I do not have.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by running the installer file as an administrator to perform the uninstall.

Windows keeps a store of the installer files.  Here's a good post on how to access those:
[Where does Windows store MSI files for uninstallation?](https://superuser.com/questions/473569/where-does-windows-store-msi-files-for-uninstallation/1517798#1517798)

I've had an easier time redownloading the installer and running it as an administrator to be able to uninstall. I now save my installers so that I can uninstall if needed.

Comment: Your solution conflicts with what you said you wanted.  You indicated you wanted to uninstall software without being an Administrator.  If you are supplying the credentials for an Administrator user then you are performing the uninstall as an Administrator.

Comment: Re downloading installers is a pointless pain in the butt.  If you look at the registry keys under "Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" you will find the uninstall command for all regular applications.  Just search from that part of the tree for the app you want to uninstall. Look for the key "UninstallString".  You can run these commands directly from an elevated command prompt.

Comment: It's not conflicting.  I very clearly specified I can run as administrator, but my user account is not an administrator account.  I'm not sure exactly how it's done from the IT side, but that's my use case.