# Windows 10 stuck in a reboot loop caused by msiexec.exe install

Tags: windows-10, windows-installer, microsoft-office-2010

My Windows 10 constantly restarts on its own without asking. Checking EventViewer, I see the restarts are caused by `The process msiexec.exe has initiated the restart of computer GEORGIE-PC on behalf of user NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM for the following reason: No title for this reason could be found Reason Code: 0x80030002 Shutdown Type: restart Comment: The Windows Installer initiated a system restart to complete or continue the configuration of 'Microsoft Office Single Image 2010'.`

This makes sense as I installed a dodgy copy of Office 2010 with KMSActivator. This gave me trouble, so I just bought a legit license for Office 2019, and the installs seems to be clashing. I tried uninstalling Office 2010 in control panel but nothing happens or sometimes it just says `language of this installation is not supported by your system`. I tried just deleted the Office2020 folders in c:\Progam Files but this didn't make any difference as I suspected. I tried the official [Microsoft Office uninstall support tool](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/uninstall-office-from-a-pc-9dd49b83-264a-477a-8fcc-2fdf5dbf61d8) but that didn't work either and always restarted in the middle. But this was actually a handy way to ensure a restart when I was testing solutions, as before the restarts would be pretty random.

Answer (score 0):

Reading about msiexec.exe, it seems to think it's in the middle of an install and needs to finish it. Thus restarting constantly, but never finishing anything. The only thing that worked for me is blowing away all traces of the install. All the following comes from this brilliant SuperUser answer: https://superuser.com/a/588251/63232

This is done in the registry. So open up regedit and go to `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\[InternalUserId]\Products\[some random guid-like sequence of chars identifying to windows your installation]\InstallProperties.`
To make this easier, just search regedit for the offending application name (Microsoft Office Single Image 2010 for me) from eventviewer below `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\` and delete it. Backup your registry before this obviously. Also delete the offending MSI filename from C:\Windows\Installer.

Now the Office uninstall support tool worked for me, but I'm not sure if I still needed to do this. Anway, end result is restarts have stopped.