# Get a specific product code

Tags: windows, windows-10, installation, windows-registry

I have `Matlab Runtime Compiler 2015b (32-bit)` installed from their [website](https://uk.mathworks.com/products/compiler/matlab-runtime.html). I'm writing a `WIX` installer which uses this `.exe`, and I'd like to check whether the product is already installed on the machine before installing it myself. In `WIX`, this can be done by searching for the `product code`, or `upgrade code`.

The issue however is that I can't seem to find any reference to the install on my computer. It exists under Add/Remove programs, and that's it.

I've tried the following:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Select-Object -Property Name | Sort-Object Name
```

---

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29937568/how-can-i-find-the-product-guid-of-an-installed-msi-setup

---

Searching through the following registries

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UpgradeCodes`

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18\Products`

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstall information exists in two branches of the registry (64 and 32 bit). Because it is a 32bit program you have to check the 32bit part.

> HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\

https://superuser.com/a/293896/471143