# How to automate uninstallation of program that I can't find the Uninstall Registry Keys for?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, windows-registry, uninstall

I have a program that I want to automate the uninstallation of, and the Control Panel lists the program and lets me run its uninstaller. It's worth mentioning that the program I want to uninstall would likely be considered to be a driver.

When I look under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` and `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` there aren't any keys related to the program. I have a test VM with only the program in question installed, so it's very easy to manually check each entry and verify that it is not present.

I know since the Control Panel is able to show it, Windows must know about it somehow.

I installed [procmon](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) and saved a log of the installation process. It captured over 2M events, but filtering by the installer process and "operation begins with Reg", I pared that down to 1701 events. I've tried to search through these, and I don't see anything that looks like what I want, although it's extremely possible that I just missed it, 1701 events is still a lot to go through.

Is there any additional filter that I can apply to try to find where it writes its uninstall string? Or is there somewhere else I should look in the registry since it's a driver?

Is there any other way I might get the uninstall string automatically? I don't really care about using the Registry specifically, although it does seem to be the best option.

Comment: Did you checked the 32 bit registry path ? https://superuser.com/a/1287510/471143

Comment: @HansHubertVogts Thank you, that did it! For what it's worth, the actual key I uncovered was not logged by procmon, so I would have never found it that way. Not sure what I would have done if it wasn't here.

Answer (score 0):

In edition to @Hans Hubert Vogts excellent comment I suggest writing a batch or vbscript to run the uninstaller. This is especially true if it is always the same program.

1. find path to uninstall.exe (usually in the install path)
2. open notpade
3. copy following code

```
start "path\to\uninstall.exe"
```

4. save as .cmd
5. run with admin privileges